# How to put the id instead of year?

Tags: php, mysql

Everyone please I really need help, I have a problem on how to put id's under the current_year. For an example in the image that's my data structure [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbAKA.png). What are the ways to save it's id not the current year I am using `$YearNow=Date('Y');`    for the current year, I would something that if the current year is 2015 after if I submit it to the database, it will save the id under the current year like `2000`

```
=======================
```

if the year of my pc is 2016 then 2016 = 2001(syearid). In my school_year table I have `(syearid(pri), from_year, to_year). And my studentvotes`(studeid(pri)autoincremtn ,candid,idno,syearid(foreign key))`. Therefore if the year of my pc is 2016 as you can see that`2016(from_year)`is under of the`syearid 2001`

here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
include('connection/connect.php');
$idnum=$_POST['idnum'];
$stat='voted';
$sqla = "UPDATE student 
      SET status=?
    WHERE idno=?";
$qa = $db->prepare($sqla);
$qa->execute(array($stat,$idnum));

$edittable=$_POST['votes'];
$a=1;
$N = count($edittable);


$YearNow=Date('Y'); 

for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{

    $sql = "UPDATE candidates
        SET votes=votes+?
        WHERE candid =? ";
        //don't know it's correct?


 $years = array();
        $sq12="select * from studentvotes,school_year where studentvotes.syearid = school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year = $YearNow";
        $result1= mysql_fetch_assoc($sq12);
            for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
             $years[$row['syearid']] = $row['from_year'];


  } 
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($a,$edittable[$i]));

    //$this part will have something to update
    $sqlas = 

"INSERT INTO studentvotes(candid,idno,syearid) VALUES (:m,:n,:o)";
    $qs = $db->prepare($sqlas);

$qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$YearNow ));
}

header("location: notification.php?". http_build_query($query));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: i cant get you ?is 2015 is saving as 2000?

Comment: You need to add more details and be clearer with your question.

Comment: I've just edited my post

Comment: where is the insert query for school_year???

Comment: inside in the for loop

Comment: its this studentvotes... not found school year..

Comment: yes,.... $qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$YearNow )); this part is my problem

Comment: try to use $qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>date('Y') ));

Comment: the same result , I want that if the year now is 2016, then it will be save the id not the year

Comment: and what should be the id in 2016????

Comment: @zeyzey   $qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$row['syearid'] ));

Comment: from the table school_year 2016(from_year) id is 2001, if 2015(from_year) is 2000

Comment: am I correct using this part?  `$years = array();
        $sq12="select * from studentvotes,school_year where studentvotes.syearid = school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year = $YearNow";
        $result1= mysql_fetch_assoc($sq12);
            for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
             $years[$row['syearid']] = $row['from_year'];


  }`

Comment: @zeyzey: use this instead of year $row['syearid']

Comment: I've got an error mysql_fetch_assoc()

Comment: @zeyzey: u have an issue in your selection using mysql and pdo together???

Comment: @devpro: yes, I change it to                                                                               `$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM studentvotes,school_year where studentvotes.syearid = school_year.syearid");
       $result->execute();`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the `mysql` and `mysqli` extension together and also using the wrong variable `$result1`. You can use like that for getting **year id**.

```
$sq12="select studentvotes.syearid from studentvotes,school_year where studentvotes.syearid = school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year = $YearNow";

$result = $db->prepare($sq12);
$result->execute();
$result_final = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$yearid = $result_final[0]; // get year id
```

Now you can insert it in your **Query**:

```
$sqlas = "INSERT INTO studentvotes(candid,idno,syearid) VALUES (:m,:n,:o)";
$qs = $db->prepare($sqlas);

$qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$yearid));
```

Comment: check this answer i hope this will work for u @zey-zey

Comment: I don't know why but it has a message of fatal error: ` Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_array() `                                                                my connection has                                                                                             `$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_database, $db_user, $db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: the problem now is the `Column 'syearid' cannot be null`

Comment: print_r($result_final).... check what r u getting in this array and than store yearid in $yearid variable... @zeyzey ...